# How to use apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.rightPad inside a JavaFX TextArea

Tags: javafx, apache-stringutils

I am using a TextArea in JavaFX to display a string that I drag into the TextArea. Inside the TextArea I want to keep a certain format. That's why I am using the `rightPad` function of the `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` library to format my string. Here is the part of my code that formats my string:

```
CustomClass myObject = (CustomClass) dragboard.getContent(customClassDataFormat);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append(myObject.getFirstCode() + "\t\t");
stringBuilder.append(StringUtils.rightPad(myObject.getStatement(), maxLength + 2));
stringBuilder.append(myObject.getLastCode() + "\n");

taextArea.appendText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

`maxLength` is a final int value that is equal to the length of the maximum statement I want to display. This variable is computed correctly and does not change its value, I verified this. I was expecting the strings that I drag into my textarea to be perfectly aligned. Instead, I obtain this:

[image]

I realize that the mismatch after the first code is due to me using `\t\t`. But even if I leave this out, the statements are not aligned. The middle part varies while it should be equal for each string (that's why I am using `rightPad`).

Does anyone know a possible reason for this behavior? Could this be the `appendText`function of the textarea that's causing this problem?

Comment: if the utils method fills the string with spaces, try a monospaced font

Comment: @kleopatra: wow. That's actually it! Thx so much, you just saved my day, I would never have guessed that